# For loop deducting each time Swift

Tags: swift

I would like to create the following effect in which the amount keep deducting.

[image]

I am able to only create this. Obviously I am missing something. If you wouldnt mind in pointing me out to the right direction.

[image]

Appreciate it peeps.

EDIT: Thanks everyone, it makes sense now. I continue to learn more each and everyday.

Comment: Would you please add some more code.

Comment: First , don't post code as an image.

Comment: You subtract the same value from the same value in each iteration. The two values never change, so neither will the result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't consider the index variable `i`

If `loan` is the initial value and `payback` is 300 then you have to calculate `loan - payback * i`

```
let loan = 5000
let payback = 300
for i in 0..<17 {
    let balance = loan - payback * i
    print(balance)
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You are saying that balance = loan - payback, but you are not modifying the value of loan or payback. I think you want to do this:

```
balance = loan
for i in (0..<12) {
  balance -= payback
  print(balance)
}
```

First we assign to balance the value of the loan and the we subtract the paybacks, getting the desired effect and also still keeping the initial value of the loan

Answer (score 3):

You have to modify loan value like below

```
balance = loan
for i in (0..<12) {
  balance = loan - payback
  loan = balance
  print(balance)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

An alternative way:  Start with `loan` and repeatedly subtract `payback`, until the number reaches zero:

```
let loan = 5000
let payback = 300

for balance in sequence(first: loan, next: { $0 - payback} ).prefix(while: { $0 > 0 }) {
    print(balance)
}
```

References:

- [`sequence(first:next:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/2015879-sequence)
- [`prefix(_:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/sequence/2886011-prefix)

Answer (score 0):

You can Try This:

```
 var aValue = 5000
    let bValue = 300
    for i in 0..<12 { //I guess the loop will be max 17 times if value is 5000 or the value will come in Negative

        let valueToMinus = bValue * i

        let cValue = aValue - valueToMinus
        print(cValue)//Resulted Output From Main
    }
```

Hope this help.